Можно ли словом "снег" проверить проверить слово "снегирь"? Опять вопросы к А. Н. Тихонову
Я давно уже имел серьезные претензии к этому 
словарю, но все не было времени написать об этом, 
но вот наконец мое терпение дошло до своего 
предела. 

Конфликт:

Школьница (2-й класс) проверяет букву Е  так: снегирь —  снег.

Однако в учебнике по русскому языку для второго класса [Канаткина, Горецкий, 2012] сказано, что слово снегирь не связано со словом снег, является первообразным, поэтому его написание надо запомнить, то есть безударную гласную в корне нельзя проверить словом снег.

Девочка  удивляется, почему это название птички, которая появляется у нас зимой, когда уже выпал снег, не связано со словом снег. Возмущению родителей просто нет предела.

Некто заметил: «А вы посмотрите в «Школьный словообразовательный словарь русского языка» А.Н.Тихонова — я почти уверен, что авторы учебника опирались на него». Придя домой, я сам заглянул в Словообразовательный словарь Тихонова и обнаружил, что слова снег и снегирь находятся
в двух особых словарных статьях, то есть каждое является первообразным; при этом слово снегирь представлено даже как нечленимое. И мое терпение дошло до предела".


Кто виноват и что делать?  Кто в этой ситуации выглядит самым малосведущим? Мне думается, что последний пользователь. Насколько виноваты остальные: дети, родители, составители учебника? И когда наконец  здесь будет наведен порядок, а Тихонов А. Н. будет пользоваться заслуженным уважением?  На форуме дня не проходи без вопросов, цель которых принизить значение его словарей и найти там множество ошибок.

«Кто в этой ситуации выглядит самым малосведущим?» === Наверное, тот «я», который потерял кавычки в своём сообщении: закрывающие есть, а вот откуда начинается цитата – ну совершенно непонятно!

Sharon: «// А кавычки все на месте, у вас зрение плохое) Ещё раз пересчитайте, или пусть поможет кто». === Ну-ну… Зрение у меня действительно не очень. Но зато я умею признавать и исправлять свои ошибки. В отличие от Вас!

Ну конечно, это не однокоренные слова.

Серж, но вот какой-то ученый муж (кафедра у него!) почему-то возмущен.  Если мы в современном языке ясно ощущаем эту связь, то, может, "подправить" словари. Кстати, какой ваш основной довод за то, что слова не родственные? http://www.drevoslov.ru/paperspdf/amk/LzheimennoeSlovoobrazovaniye.pdf

Возможно, этимологически они родственны, что подтверждается этимологическими словарями. Однако, есть и другая версия, согласно которой, слово происходить от тюркского "сниг", что означает красногрудый. Даже в армянском эта птичка так и называется.

Но сегодня между ними нет никакой связи.

По поводу этимологии у меня нет сомнений. Посмотрела словарь Черных, у него о.-с. основа snegъ, и.-е. корень snigh, похожие основы есть в греческом и латинском языке, у всех значение снег.  В древнерусском языке слово с 11 века. И в любом случае в сознании русских пользователей название птицы связано со снегом.

Ответ Грамоты читали,который я провел ниже. Вернее ссылку на ответ.

Серж, я сейчас только прочитала ответ Грамоты, и полностью с ним согласна.  У слов снег и снегирь есть историческая связь по смыслу, но нет ЖИВЫХ словообразовательных связей. Это значит, что нет модели, позволяющей образовать сущ. от сущ. с помощью суффикса ИРЬ. Я это первым делом посмотрела у Ефремовой. // А вы не могли бы дать ответ с этим комментарием Грамоты, чтобы закрыть тему. Те ответы,  которые даны, меня однозначно не устраивают.


ОТВЕТЫ СПРАВОЧНОЙ СЛУЖБЫ

Вопрос № 317153.
Здравствуйте! На вопрос 259537, являются ли слова снег и снегирь однокоренными, вы ответили, что "В СОВРЕМЕННОМ РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ ЭТИ СЛОВА НЕ ОДНОКОРЕННЫЕ".
Однако в Орфографические комментарии русского языка написано, что эти слова однокоренные. Также и в этих пособиях эти слова считаются однокоренными. Баронова Марина Марковна. Правописание безударных гласных ; Две согласные или одна : школьные словари русского языка для подготовки к урокам, ГИА и ЕГЭ. М., 2011, Рацибурская Лариса Викторовна. Словарь уникальных морфем современного русского языка. М., 2009. Не могли бы вы прокомментировать из чего исходили составители пособия Орфографические комментарии русского языка?
ОТВЕТ. Вы имеете  в виду ресурс «Орфографическое комментирование русского словаря»? В качестве проверочных слов здесь нередко даются слова исторически родственные, но в современном русском языке уже не являющиеся однокоренными. Главная задача этого ресурса — объяснить, почему слово пишется именно так, а не иначе. Ответ на этот вопрос часто можно дать, только обратившись к прошлому языка.
Слова снег и снегирь в современном русском языке не являются однокоренными, потому что сейчас между ними нет ЖИВОЙ словообразовательной связи: значение слова снегирь нельзя объяснить через значение слова снег (в отличие, например, от слов снегопад, снеговик, снежинка).

Что же, ответ Грамоты.ру исчерпывающий. Не изучайте грамматику по орфографическим пособиям.
Орфография и грамматика – разные науки.  
В словообразовании есть определенные принципы, 
аксиомы, определения, модели по которым 
образуются слова и т. д. И этими принципами 
практическая орфография управлять никак не 
может. Орфография – прикладная наука и во многом  
подчиняется грамматике, основана на ней, но 
никак не наоборот. 


Мой комментарий относительно живой связи


Снеги́рь. Название этой птички образовано от существительного снъгъ и объясняется тем, что она прилетает в среднюю полосу с Севера вместе с первым снегом и заморозками.
Снеги́рь. Искон. Суф. производное (суф. -ырь) от снѣгъ. Снѣгырь после изменения кы, гы, хы в ки, ги, хи > снѣгирь, а затем в результате ассимиляции ѣ последующему и > снигирь. Птица названа так потому, что прилетает к нам с севера вместе с первым снегом и заморозками.
Схема образования слова (11 век) в древнерусском языке: снѣгъ — снѣгырь. В современном произношении и графике: снегирь.
В современном языке самая близкая словообразовательная модель выглядит так: пустой — пустырь, суффикс ЫРЬ выделяется в сущ. м. рода со значением пространства, названного именем прилагательным.
Очевидно, что с помощью подобной модели сложно объяснить образование сущ. снегирь от сущ. снег с помощью унификса ИРЬ. В любом случае  в школьном образовании эта модель рассматриваться не будет. Также учтем, что слово было образовано еще в древнерусском языке с помощью суффикса ЫРЬ, а не ИРЬ, причем суффикс ЫРЬ есть в современном языке.


Можно ли словом "снег" проверить проверить слово "снегирь"?

Если в каких-то пособиях, учебниках или словарях такая проверка рекомендуется, то, конечно, МОЖНО. Тем более, что она даёт положительный результат.
А она рядом пособий рекомендуется.
См., к примеру:
Баронова, Марина Марковна. Правописание безударных гласных ; Две согласные или одна : школьные словари русского языка для подготовки к урокам, ГИА и ЕГЭ. М., 2011:



Рацибурская Лариса Викторовна. Словарь уникальных морфем современного русского языка. М., 2009:



Проверка безударной гласной в слове снегирь словом снег рекомендуется в настоящее время и справочником «ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКОЕ КОММЕНТИРОВАНИЕ РУССКОГО СЛОВАРЯ»:

снеги́рь проверка: снег
◊ В 18 – 19 вв. слово писалось с буквой и – снигирь…


СПРАВОЧНАЯ СЛУЖБА. № 259537
Слова "снегирь" и "снег" однокоренные?
ОТВЕТ
В современном русском языке эти слова не однокоренные.  // Не стоит приветствовать всех сторонников лженаучного подхода . Грамматика — наука серьезная, дилетантам там делать нечего. Сказано — не однокоренные, значит, так оно и есть))  // Особенный ВРЕД для современной школы, где приветствуются единые базовые знания по предметам.  У нас образование стали получать по Пособиям для ОГЭ и ЕГЭ.

Sharon: «Грамматика — наука серьезная, дилетантам там делать нечего». === ❓❓❓ Вы к дилетантам, как я понял, и Рацибурскую относите, на словарь которой и сами недавно ссылались?

Участник Слава! Вы меня не ловите на цитатах, а отвечайте по существу. Почему вы пропагандируете НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЕ ЗНАНИЯ на нашем форуме? Я могу ДОКАЗАТЬ  правильность словаря Тихонова и ответов Грамоты, но пока не буду этого делать. Докажите вы СВОЮ ТОЧКУ ЗРЕНИЯ по сути, а не ссылаясь на книжки.

Sharon: «Участник Слава! Вы меня не ловите на цитатах, а отвечайте по существу. Почему вы пропагандируете НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЕ ЗНАНИЯ на нашем форуме?» === Ну почему же Вы НЕКОРРЕКТНЫМИ считаете те знания, что можно получить из современных академических источников? ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ: «Словарь уникальных морфем» издан издательством «ФЛИНТА/НАУКА».

Школьница 2-го класса должна выделить УНИКАЛЬНУЮ морфему ИРЬ в снегирь?   Вы именно это хотели сказать?  В исконных  словах уникальные части восходят к неуникальным аффиксальным?  Это должен знать школьник? Цитата:  Такие уникальные части слов с трудом можно назвать морфемами, так как они характеризуются семантической недостаточностью.  https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/unikalnye-morfemy-svyazannye-korni-unifiksy   // Вы любите отыскивать разные книжки, но совершенно не ориентируетесь  в них. И постоянно противопоставляете академическому словарю Тихонова свои находки. Это выглядит странно.

Sharon: «И постоянно противопоставляете академическому словарю Тихонова…» === Sharon, с чего Вы взяли, что словарь Тихонова — академический?

И, кстати, школьница 2-го класса совсем не должна знать про словарь Тихонова. А вот уловить связь между словами снегирь и снег она может, и тогда не ошибётся в написании безударной гласной.

Школьники должны уметь работать со следующими словарями: толковый, морфемный, словообразовательный, этимологический. Всё это есть в Сети. Смотрим этимологический словарь: Снеги́рь. Искон. Суф. производное (суф. -ырь) от снѣгъ. Снѣгырь после изменения кы, гы, хы в ки, ги, хи > снѣгирь. Птица названа так потому, что прилетает к нам с севера вместе с первым снегом и заморозками.  Так что не ошибется на письме и дополнительные знания получит. Это исторически родственные слова. Таких примеров этимологической проверки слов много.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/с/снегирь

«ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКОЕ КОММЕНТИРОВАНИЕ РУССКОГО СЛОВАРЯ»?  Слышала об этой книге отрицательные отзывы.  // Орфография и грамматика - разные науки,   И вот в словообразовании есть определенные принципы, аксиомы, определения, модели по которым образуются слова и т. д. И этими принципами   практическая орфография управлять никак не может, как бы вам этого ни хотелось.  Это не слишком грамотно мешать одно с другим.  Орфография в основном подчиняется грамматике, основана на ней, но никак не наоборот. Приведу еще один пример подобной ситуации  https://proza.ru/2021/06/14/301

Sharon: «Слышала об этой книге отрицательные отзывы» === От кого, не поделитесь?

Я уж и не вспомню)) Мне она тоже не нравится, чисто практическое освоение грамотного письма приближенными, а иногда и сомнительными методами.  Вообще говоря,  у нас в качестве пособий пропускают иногда книги ну очень странные. Свои люди, наверное)

Ответ Грамоты ру. https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/317153

Проверять снегирь снегом на ЭГЭ это слишком... Надеюсь, это не официальное пособие.

В КАЧЕСТВЕ ОТВЕТА НА КОММЕНТАРИИ К МОЕМУ ОТВЕТУ В ЭТОЙ ТЕМЕ
Вот как предлагается сейчас находить корень в слове снегирь в одном из справочников по русскому языку для начальной школы:


(Герасимович, Нина Леонидовна. Все правила по русскому языку. 1-4 классы : для начальной школы : [для младшего школьного возраста : 0+]. Москва, 2020)

Ужас!  Бедные  дети младшего школьного возраста : 0+ Спасибо вам за сигнал, надо обсудить этот вопрос и обратиться в Министерство образования за разъяснениями.  А пока ни в коем случае не покупайте НЕДОРОГО  книгу Нины Леонидовны ГЕРАСИМОВИЧ по специальной цене 6О4 рубля))

А это вам в подарок)) Кабы не было зимы, в этом нет секрета -
От жары устали б мы, надоело б лето.
Не пришла бы к нам метель на денёк хотя бы,
И снегирь не сел на ель, кабы, кабы, кабы...  https://my.mail.ru/music/songs/марина-девятова-кабы-не-было-зимы-f9d6108a69cf30e7dbfe2c05969b9114
